# Subdivisions of a plane somehow ignored when bending it with a Curve modifier and a BezierCircle

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I'm trying to bend a sufficently subdivided plane with a BezierCircle. For the BezierCircle, in order to be as round as possible I added a subdivision modifier "Catmull-Clark" with 6 subdivisions for viewport and render. The circle became significantly more round with that change.

In the vieport the situation is looking as follows:

[image]

Not really nice, although the BezierCircle seems perfect..... Initially I did assume that this is just a viewport issue in order to reduce the complexity for fast editing. However, after checking this in detail the situation is looking identical in the render output. What can go wrong here?

Thanks,
Mario

Comment: @JohnEason Thousand thanks! That did the trick :-) "Preview Resolution U" was set to 12. When I pump it up to 64 I get a smooth alignment. And, indeed I can remove the BezierCircle subdivision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increase the <kbd>Resolution Preview</kbd> in the Bezier Circle properties (indicated below). If you set <kbd>Render U</kbd> to <kbd>0</kbd>, the render resolution will be taken from the Preview properties. You can also remove the Subdiv Surface modifier from the Bezier Circle.
[image]